# Unable to install docker - invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed

Tags: server, docker

Currently unable to install docker on `Ubuntu 16.04`. (when I **have** been able to previously). After running `sudo apt-get install docker-ce` (as per [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package)) I get the following message:

> Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
>
> docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
>      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
>              └─10-machine.conf
>
> Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-09-07 21:44:50 BST; 3ms ago
>        Docs: https://docs.docker.com
>
> Process: 15332 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver aufs --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=generic (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>    Main PID: 15332 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

`systemctl status docker.service` does not really give anymore detail. `journalctl -xe` shows the following (summary):

> Sep 07 21:56:45 mpt systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package): Starting Docker Socket for the API.
>
> Sep 07 21:56:45 mpt systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package): Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
>
> Sep 07 21:56:45 mpt systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package): docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
>
> Sep 07 21:56:45 mpt systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package): Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
>
> -- The result is failed.
>   Sep 07 21:56:45 mpt systemd[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package): docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
>   Sep 07 21:56:46 mpt sudo[16052]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

When I run `apt-get install` again I get this message:

> 1 not fully installed or removed.1

*(In addition to the error I previously mentioned.)*

The solution to that was:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker*
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
```

I had been trying to get to `docker-machine` to work from my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) to this machine so I guess this could have caused some issue.

I'm a bit stuck. Any help and suggestions really appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the following files in `/etc/systemd/system/`

- docker.service
- docker.service.d
- docker.socket

Removing these, in addition to the removal commands mentioned above resulted in the error going away.

Comment: I'm getting this error and those files were already missing.