# Docker installation fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, docker

I am attempting to install Docker following the instructions given in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

The download of files succeeds, but the post-installation script fails:

```
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-08-21 11:44:55 CDT; 3ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 138394 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 138394 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There isn't much ancillary information available:

```
user@machine:~$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-08-21 11:45:03 CDT; 29s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 138847 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 138847 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Looking at `journalctl -xe` provides no information, there are no log entries corresponding to these installation attempts.

The error line is referenced [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953726/unable-to-install-docker-invoke-rc-d-initscript-docker-action-start-failed) but that is pretty old and I tried a full removal and file purge to no effect. The kernel issues reported around that issue seem to be related to some past time where docker no longer supported kernel versions under 3.10. I'm on 5.11 and I don't see any indication that this is a problem any more.

This may be a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356869/docker-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04-fails), but I don't speak Russian so not sure. That question isn't answered anyways.

Comment: Could you please edit your post, and include all commands you ran and their respective output during installation? This is the only way to follow the trail and see what might be the problem.

Comment: Also, did you remember this VERY important part of removing the old versions first? `sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`